# http handler not showing image

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I am trying to retrive image from the database which have column of type image actually i have table from one table i want to show image and from another table i want to retrive other fields i am using form view

aspx file

```
<asp:FormView runat="server" ID="ListStories" DefaultMode="ReadOnly" >
<ItemTemplate>
<table>
<tr><td><%#Eval("Subject") %></td></tr>
<tr><td><%#Eval("Story") %></td></tr>
<tr><td><%#Eval("UserName")%> <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl='~/ShowImage.ashx?Name=<%#Eval("UserName") %>' Width="150" Height="150" /></td></tr>

</table>
</ItemTemplate>


</asp:FormView>
```

Code behind:

```
string connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Alumnidb"].ConnectionString;
    SqlConnection conn;
    SqlCommand cmdStories;
    SqlDataReader reader;


    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RetriveStories();

    }

    protected void RetriveStories()
    {

        conn = new SqlConnection(connString);
        //cmdStories = new SqlCommand("SELECT Stories.UserName, Stories.Subject, Stories.Story, UserProfile.Photo FROM Stories INNER JOIN UserProfile ON UserProfile.UserName=Stories.UserName", conn);
        cmdStories = new SqlCommand("SELECT UserName, Subject, Story FROM Stories",conn);
        conn.Open();
        reader = cmdStories.ExecuteReader();


        ListStories.DataSource = reader;
        ListStories.DataBind();

        conn.Close();

    }
```

HttpHandler:

```
public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context) {
        byte[] buffer = null;
        string querySqlStr = "";
        if (context.Request.QueryString["Name"] != null)
        {
            querySqlStr = "SELECT Photo from UserProfile where UserName=" + context.Request.QueryString["Name"];
        }

        conn = new SqlConnection(connString);
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(querySqlStr, conn);
        SqlDataReader reader = null;
        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            //get the extension name of image
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                string name = reader["Photo"].ToString();
                int endIndex = name.LastIndexOf('.');
                string extensionName = name.Remove(0, endIndex + 1);
                buffer = (byte[])reader["imageContent"];
                context.Response.Clear();
                context.Response.ContentType = "image/" + extensionName;
                context.Response.BinaryWrite(buffer);
                context.Response.Flush();
                context.Response.Close();
            }
            reader.Close();

        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
        }
    }
    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

It shows fields from one table but not showing the image from another table. . 
where am i getting wrong?
Your help will be appreciated. . .Thanx

Comment: First of all, DO NOT USE string concatenation in sql queries

Comment: @kostasch.:Ok, but will you please tell me why it is not working

Comment: check size of your imageContent column in db.

Comment: Also do you have any exception in handler code while debugging?

Comment: @aamir: it shows 16 in property window

Comment: @kostasch.: no exceptions just asp:image control shows nothing while other fields are showing

Comment: Debug and check that request to handler is working or not .

Comment: Please check my post again. The bold one.

Comment: Ok please guide me which path? as i retrieving it from db. Sorry for inconvenience

Comment: The path of your image in the filesystem. :)

Comment: i am not using file system. . images are in db

Comment: I know, so check my post again.

Comment: Thanx for the article. .. but i couldn't understand it according to my scenario will you please give me some example please.Sorry for inconvenience

Answer (score 0):

You should use that

```
 if (context.Request.QueryString["Name"] != null)
    {
        querySqlStr = "SELECT Photo from UserProfile where UserName= @username" ;

    }

    conn = new SqlConnection(connString);
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(querySqlStr, conn);.
    command.Parameters.Add("@username",context.Request.QueryString["Name"]);
```

But as you have it must be with single quotes

```
querySqlStr = "SELECT Photo from UserProfile where UserName='" + context.Request.QueryString["Name"] + "'";
```

As i said in my comment DO NOT USE string concatenation. You will gain many things. **But i think your problem is that you are trying to put in `ImageUrl` byte[]. It just need path.**

See this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.image.imageurl.aspx

If you want to load byte[] in your image follow the above article.
http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/445876/Auto-bind-byte-to-asp-Image

Comment: Also check the query in db if it returns something.

Comment: @user2517610 Try and the other. As i said, try to run the query in sql to detect what the return is.